# Sun Java on Linux and automating updates

Tags: linux, java

I am running Graylog v2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 which doesn't work with OpenJDK so I routinely download  the Sun Java JRE and install it to `/usr/local/bin` and start Graylog accordingly.

Besides checking Sun's Java download page regularly, is there any way of automatically keeping my server updated with the latest Sun Java version?

EDIT: added distro info

I've stumbled across the [webupd8team](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-debian-8) repo; is this considered the best way to stay updated?

Comment: Depends entirely on your distribution.

Comment: Yes, add the webupd8team repo/ppa, install Java via apt, and it will keep updated.